# controller_manager and controller library on different machines

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a 2-machine ROS setup.

M1 is connected to the robot, and runs the node that starts `controller_manager` (`franka_control_node` from [`franka_control`](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros/tree/kinetic-devel/franka_control)).

I developed a new controller on M2. For example, something copied from [`franka_example_controllers`](https://github.com/frankaemika/franka_ros/tree/kinetic-devel/franka_example_controllers).

Is it possible that the `controller_manager` running on M1 can run the controller from M2?

Currently I get the error `Failed to load <controller_name>`. Running `rosservice call /controller_manager/list_controller_types` does not show the new controller.

Everything works if I move the controller code to M1 and build it there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367563/controller_manager-and-controller-library-on-different-machines/) by [samarth.robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39083/samarth.robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not possible. When a `controller_manager` loads a controller, it will use `pluginlib` to load the requested controller (which is simply a correctly exported library) into its own process. This `pluginlib` lookup will (naturally) only be able to look for this library on its current system. This is why you won't be able to get around moving/copying your controller over to M2.

More generally, it often helps to remind oneself that `ros_control` looks like a whole bunch of components working together, but at the end of the day they will all run in one node/process through dynamic library loading. My workflow in similar situations mostly consisted of developing a controller on M1 (including small tests in simulation), and then just moving it over using `scp`/`git` or similar.

---

Originally posted by [RobertWilbrandt](https://answers.ros.org/users/64579/robertwilbrandt/) with karma: 176 on 2020-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samarth.robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/39083/samarth.robo/) on 2020-12-14**:
That makes sense, thank you!